# Extracting usernames from the /etc/passwd file

Tags: command-line

What command(s) would you use to extract all of the usernames from a database called `/etc/passwd` and then sort this output alphabetically in reverse order?

Answer (score 3):

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | sort -r
```

or

```
awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd | sort -r
```

Actually, if you're on a system that uses nsswitch (e.g. most, if not all, Linux distros and many other *nixes these days) , you should use `getent passwd` instead of just reading `/etc/passwd` as there are many other possible sources of user account data (including LDAP and nis or yp):

```
getent passwd | cut -d: -f1 | sort -r
getent passwd | awk -F: '{print $1}' | sort -r
```

Comment: Thank  you. The cut commands seems a lot simpler and cleaner for just the basic. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If your want to list real people that have their home directory in /home you could filter the list as it :

    `grep home /etc/passwd|cut -d: -f1`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/:.*//' /etc/passwd | sort -r
```

`sed` is the **s**tream **ed**itor, which is used to apply text editing commands to streams of text data.  `sed` uses *regular expressions* to match patterns in the lines of text.  *Regular expressions* are common to many Unix/Linux commands such as grep, awk, emacs, vi, perl, python etc. so learning regular expressions will improve your skills with many different commands.

The above sed command executes the `s` (substitute) function on each line of text.  The basic `s` command works like this:

```
    `s/regular expression/replacement/`
```

The regular expression in this `sed` command `:.*` matches the first colon on the line, if any, followed by 0 or more (`*`) of any other characters (`.`) to the (implied) end of line.  `sed` replaces whatever is matched by this with nothing and prints the results.

In other words, this sed command deletes from the first colon to the end of the line before printing the line.

Comment: Thank, you. I think  cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | sort -r   is a better basic command for a beginner. Although, I don't think I understand what the f1 means.

Comment: `-f1` tells cut to extract the first field, field number 1.  the `-d:` tells cut that fields are delimited by `:` characters.

Comment: @user140352 You're welcome.  You won't be a beginner forever!  :-)  Just FYI I'll add some more explanation.